# How to loop through worksheets in a defined order using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below working code which loops through each worksheet and if the value defined in the range (myrange) is 'Y', it outputs those sheets into a single PDF document.  My challange is that i want to define the order that they are output in the PDF based on the number value in the range (for example 1,2,3,4,5,6,7 etc) instead of 'Y'.  I plan on using the same column in the myrange to check whether it needs to be output to PDF, by simply swapping the 'Y' for a number, such as '1' and '2'.

Currently the order is defined based on the location of the worksheet tabs. from left to right.

Any help will be much appreciated.

```
Sub Run_Me_To_Create_Save_PDF()

    Dim saveAsName          As String
    Dim WhereTo             As String
    Dim sFileName           As String
    Dim ws                  As Worksheet
    Dim printOrder          As Variant '**added**
    Dim myrange

    On Error GoTo Errhandler

    Sheets("Settings").Activate

' Retrieve value of 'Period Header' from Settings sheet
    Range("C4").Activate
    periodName = ActiveCell.Value

' Retrieve value of 'File Name' from Settings sheet
    Range("C5").Activate
    saveAsName = ActiveCell.Value

' Retrieve value of 'Publish PDF to Folder' from Settings sheet
    Range("C6").Activate
    WhereTo = ActiveCell.Value

    Set myrange = Worksheets("Settings").Range("range_sheetProperties")

' Check if Stamp-field has any value at all and if not, add the current date.
    If Stamp = "" Then Stamp = Date

' Assemble the filename
    sFileName = WhereTo & saveAsName & " (" & Format(CDate(Date), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ").pdf"

' Check whether worksheet should be output in PDF, if not hide the sheet
    For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

        Sheets(ws.Name).Visible = True
        printOrder = Application.VLookup(ws.Name, myrange, 4, False)

        If Not IsError(printOrder) Then

            If printOrder = "Y" Then
                Sheets(ws.Name).Visible = True
            End If
            Else: Sheets(ws.Name).Visible = False
        End If

    Next

'Save the File as PDF
    ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    sFileName, Quality _
    :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True

' Unhide and open the Settings sheet before exiting
    Sheets("Settings").Visible = True
    Sheets("Settings").Activate
    MsgBox "PDF document has been created and saved to : " & sFileName

    Exit Sub

Errhandler:

' If an error occurs, unhide and open the Settings sheet then display an error message
    Sheets("Settings").Visible = True
    Sheets("Settings").Activate
    MsgBox "An error has occurred. Please check that the PDF is not already open."


End Sub
```

**---------------------- UPDATE: -------------------------------------**

Thank you for all your input so far.  I did get it to work briefly, but with more playing i've become stuck.  I am now receiving a 'Subscript our of range' error with the below code at :

```
If sheetNameArray(x) <> Empty Then
```

Any ideas?

```
        Sub Run_Me_To_Create_Save_PDF()

        Dim saveAsName                  As String
        Dim WhereTo                     As String
        Dim sFileName                   As String
        Dim ws                          As Worksheet
        Dim myrange
        ReDim sheetNameArray(0 To 5) As String
        Dim NextWs                      As Worksheet
        Dim PreviousWs                  As Worksheet
        Dim x                           As Integer

    'On Error GoTo Errhandler

        Sheets("Settings").Activate

    ' Retrieve value of 'Period Header' from Settings sheet
        Range("C4").Activate
        periodName = ActiveCell.Value

    ' Retrieve value of 'File Name' from Settings sheet
        Range("C5").Activate
        saveAsName = ActiveCell.Value

    ' Retrieve value of 'Publish PDF to Folder' from Settings sheet
        Range("C6").Activate
        WhereTo = ActiveCell.Value

    ' Check if Stamp-field has any value at all and if not, add the current date.
        If Stamp = "" Then Stamp = Date

    ' Assemble the filename
        sFileName = WhereTo & saveAsName & " (" & Format(CDate(Date), "DD-MMM-YYYY") & ").pdf"

        Set myrange = Worksheets("Settings").Range("range_sheetProperties")

        For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets

            printOrder = Application.VLookup(ws.Name, myrange, 4, False)

            If Not IsError(printOrder) Then
                printOrderNum = printOrder
                If printOrderNum <> Empty Then
    'Add sheet to array
                    num = printOrderNum - 1
                    sheetNameArray(num) = ws.Name
                End If
            End If

        Next

        MsgBox Join(sheetNameArray, ",")

'Order Tab sheets based on array
        x = 1
        Do While Count < 6
            If sheetNameArray(x) <> Empty Then

                Set PreviousWs = Sheets(sheetNameArray(x - 1))
                Set NextWs = Sheets(sheetNameArray(x))
                NextWs.Move after:=PreviousWs
                x = x + 1
            Else
                Count = Count + 1
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Loop

        Sheets(sheetNameArray).Select

    'Save the File as PDF
        ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=sFileName, Quality _
        :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True

    ' open the Settings sheet before exiting
        Sheets("Settings").Activate
        MsgBox "PDF document has been created and saved to : " & sFileName

        Exit Sub

Errhandler:

    ' If an error occurs, unhide and open the Settings sheet then display an error message
        Sheets("Settings").Visible = True
        Sheets("Settings").Activate
        MsgBox "An error has occurred. Please check that the PDF is not already open."


    End Sub
```

Comment: Subscript out of range in an array would usually indicate that the boundaries of the array have been exceeded or simply, you are trying to use a number for x that is outside the limits of the array.  so if you have x = 1, that would be like trying to get the SECOND element in the array, when there is only ONE...  (0)1st, (1)2nd.

Check the LOCALS window and see how many elements your array has when that error happens.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bit of code I came up with. Basically you would want to take this and adapt it to fit your specific needs but the general idea should work!

```
Sub MovingPagesAccordingToNumberInRange()

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim NextWs As Worksheet
    Dim PreviousWs As Worksheet
    Dim sheetNameArray(0 To 400) As String
    Dim i As Integer

    'This first loop is taking all of the sheets that have a number
    ' placed in the specified range (I used Cell A1 of each sheet)
    ' and it places the name of the worksheet into an array in the
    ' order that I want the sheets to appear. If I placed a 1 in the cell
    ' it will move the name to the 1st place in the array (location 0).
    ' and so on. It only places the name however when there is something
    ' in that range.

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        If ws.Cells(1, 1).Value <> Empty Then
            num = ws.Cells(1, 1).Value - 1
            sheetNameArray(num) = ws.Name
        End If
    Next

    ' This next section simply moves the sheets into their
    ' appropriate positions. It takes the name of the sheets in the
    ' previous spot in the array and moves the current spot behind that one.
    ' Since I didn't know how many sheets you would be using I just put
    ' A counter in the prevent an infinite loop. Basically if the loop encounters 200
    ' empty spots in the array, everything has probably been organized.
    x = 1
    Do While Count < 200
        If sheetNameArray(x) <> Empty Then

            Set PreviousWs = sheets(sheetNameArray(x - 1))
            Set NextWs = sheets(sheetNameArray(x))
            NextWs.Move after:=PreviousWs
            x = x + 1
        Else
            Count = Count + 1
            x = x + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, please see my original post for some updates.  I'm almost there i beleive.

Answer (score 1):

You would want to define the worksheets in an array.

This example uses a static array, knowing the sheets order and what you want to print in advance.  This does work.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(Array("Sheet1","Sheet2","Sheet6","Master","Sales")).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=sFileName, Quality _
    :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=True
```

The problem is that if a sheet is hidden, it will fail on the selection.

So you will need to already know which sheets pass the test to be printed or not before declaring the Array. Therefore you will need a dynamic array to build the list of Worksheets.

I did change how your PrintOrder works, instead of making the sheet invisible, it simply doesn't add it to the array, or vice versa, adds the ones you want to the array.  Then you select the array at the end, and run your print macro that works.

I tested this using my own test values, and am trusting that your PrintOrder Test works.  But this does work.  I used it to print time sheets that only have more than 4 hours per day, and it succeeded, merging 5 sheets out of a workbook with 11 sheets into one PDF..  All of them qualified the test.

**TESTED:**  Insert this instead of your For Each ws and add the Variable Declarations with yours

```
Sub DynamicSheetArray()
    Dim wsArray() As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim wsCount As Long

    wsCount = 0

    For Each ws In Worksheets
        printOrder = Application.VLookup(ws.Name, myrange, 4, False)
        If Not IsError(printOrder) Then
            If printOrder = "Y" Then
                wsCount = wsCount + 1
                ReDim Preserve wsArray(1 To wsCount)
                'Add sheet to array
                wsArray(wsCount) = ws.Name
            End If
        End If
    Next

    Sheets(wsArray).Select

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, fileName:=sFileName, Quality _
        :=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
        OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

edit:  further explained context of my code to OP

Comment: This answer doesn't actually address the core of your question, upon reflection.  That the order isn't getting done correctly.  I am leaving it up because it shows an alternative to hiding and un-hiding the worksheets in order to print them, and in that it's a solution.  But the order is still the same.  The other answer might provide a clue as to shifting the order, and perhaps a hybrid of both is what you are looking for.

Comment: If you get it working using a hybrid, please post it as an answer, because I'm very interested in knowing the answer too at this point.

Comment: Getting close but not there yet. I've added the update in my original question, hopefully you'll know more? P.S i've ready that the ExportAsFixedFormat will always order based on the tab index, therefore even through the array was ordered correctly, the export to PDF was not.  Therefore the only solution is to move the tabs around before exporting to PDF.  Thanks

Comment: check my latest update, i forgot to include a section of the code 7 mins ago.  It's also worth noting that the sheet tabs are actually all being arranged correctly and then i receive the error.